# Textures and pixel storage

Tags: opengl, textures

Right now I have an application that renders a geometry and allows you to select a PNG and overlay it. My question is this:

I have a scenario where I select a PNG where the width is not a multiple of 4 (the dimensions are 2719 x 1277).

My understanding is that if you try to store an image into a 2D texture who's dimensions aren't multiples of 4 this shouldn't work. At least if your GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT is 4, which mine is.

I'm storing my texture with an internal format of RGB so one row if pixels would be 2719 * 3 (8157). I've seen problems people have had where they're trying to do the same thing I am where their image width is not in a multiple of 4, and they haven't been able to use the texture, until they've set the unpack alignment to 1, but in my case it works if I use 4. I just wanna understand why this is.

I used this link as my primary learning source.

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer

Comment: THere are many possible explanations. For example, it could be as simple as your image loader adding some alignment. Also the _internalFormat_ does not matter, but only the client side format.

Comment: Yea I hadnt even considered the possibility that the image loader was responsible, and thats in fact what it was.  The image loader aligns the data in such a way that the byte count is a multiple of 4 so it would work for me regardless.  Thanks a alot!